# Is there a special term describing mental translation between L1 and L2?

Tags: terminology

Is there a special term to describe the mental translation of a word? E.g. when one sees a recently learned term, they may think of the L1 meaning rather than directly think of the concept.

Answer (score 2):

I think your term is fine.  It's used in existing research, for example Richard G. Kern's 1994 paper [*The Role of Mental Translation in Second Language Reading*](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2552820).  This is helpfully discussed in chapter six of Andrew Cohen's book, [*Strategies in Learning and Using a Second Language*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1408253992).

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you re looking for is Code Switching. Though this term focuses on the change of language among speakers of more than one language, perhaps a deep analysis of this "linguistic" code switch would reveal that it goes in parallel with a cognitive "code switch". I mean code switching occurs at two levels: cognitive and linguistic. As far as i know, there is no term describing this phenomenon.

Comment: Does anyone use 'code switching' to refer to mental translation? If you're the first to suggest it then you should be more explicit.

Comment: My understanding of the term code-switching is that a speaker is producing two different languages/variants and not thinking about one language and then producing another, which is what I believe the question is asking for (but I might have misunderstood). So I'd say that "code switching" is not what the original question is asking for.